# If you take the standard tax deduction, can you still claim the Child Tax Credit?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction, children

If you take the standard tax deduction, can you still claim the Child Tax Credit? I can't find the answer with Google.

Answer (score 6):

The Child Tax Credit is a credit, not a deduction, so you do not need to itemize to get the credit.

Qualification is based on your adjusted gross income, which is calculated before the standard deduction and most itemized deductions.

The tax credit, $2000 per child, is 'refundable' up to $1400 per child. This simply means that if you look at your tax bill, pre-credit, and the tax is less than ($2000 * # of children) that you can actually get a refund of up to $1400 per child and end the year with a 'profit'.

Comment: D - feel free to edit or delete what I just added. It's an important point for those with kids who don't quite understand how valuable the credit is. A refund, even if you paid less, or no tax, against income during the year.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer+ including those unaware that CTC/ACTC increased as of 2018, and remember or find stale info about the previous less-valuable version